# React Native UI freezed when function is executing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

In my React Native app, I have a component that executes a heavy task in `componentDidMount`. The function deals with  time series so they are considerably large objects. The problem ww are seeing is:  when the component mounts and the function start executing, the app UI freezes. Only the component's `ScrollView` works, all the `Touchables` freeze and the TabNavigator also stops working until the function ends executing and returns. After the end of the execution, the app works normally.

Is there anyway I can solve this performance issue?

Comment: You can use promises or async/await to run code in parallel. Here are some good docs on using promises in Javascript: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises. I'd start there.

Comment: I already tried using promises but the UI still freezes until the promise is resolved

Answer (score 0):

You can try to break up the workload in multiple parts and put them in a queue. Then process the queue with a small setTimeout delay between each job. That will give the UI time to respond.

Another option would be to offload the work to native code so it can run in different thread.